# Display progress of a long mysql query using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Im trying to display the progress percentage of a long mysql query using php
I have button to make the filter in my database , that runs a js function that calls using ajax a php file

```
function show(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"backend.php",
            type:"POST",
            beforeSend:function(){      
                $("body").addClass("loading");
            },
            success:function(data){
                $("tbody").html(data);
                $("body").removeClass("loading");
            }
        });
    }
```

and i have a loading div

```
<div class="mod">
    <h1>Progress :  <input type="text" id="percents"></span>       
</div>
```

on my backend file , i fetch the result using foreach loop on tbody

inside that tbody , i increment a $counter then calculate the percentage using

```
$percent = ($conteur/$total) * 100;
```

Now, when i write javascript code inside the loop , like alert or console.log it works perfectly and display the percentage progress

```
while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($rs1)){ 
    $conteur++;
    $percent = ($conteur/$total) * 100;
    $cust_perc=$percent;?>
    <script>document.getElementById("percents").value = <?php echo $cust_perc ?>+" %";</script> 
  <tr>
      <th>Centrale</th>
      <td><?php echo $row1[5];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row1[0];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row1[1];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row1[2];?></td>  
      <td><?php echo ($row1[4]/1000)." T"; $tonnage+=($row1[4]/1000); 
           $tonnage_roch+=($row1[4]/1000);?></td>  
      <td>-</td>
      <td><?php echo $row1[3];?></td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td><?php echo $row1[6];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row1[7];?></td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>               
  </tr>
 <?php          
  } ?>
```

but when i try to make change in my loading div input , mytable looks endomaged and no changes done !!

can someone has an idea please ?

Comment: `Now, when i write javascript code inside the loop `-> which loop?

Comment: Could you also paste the code for updating your id="percents" span..

Comment: Post updated with the foreach loop and updating id="percents"

Comment: If it's a run longing query because it's fetching/processing a huge amount of data then you might want to look into paginating the results.  If it's long running because your query is slow you might want to look into optimising the query (removing redundant joins/columns, making sure the tables are properly indexed and that the query is using the indexes you think it should be, etc).  Either way, improving the query performance should be your first port of call.

Comment: Also, I notice you're using mysql_* functions.  These have been deprecated in PHP 5.x and REMOVED ENTIRELY in PHP 7.  You should not do any new development with mysql_* and instead switch to mysqli or PDO.

Comment: GordonM , tables are properly indexed and im already using pagination but the amount of data that i have is huge, i have more than 1 milion data and im making a filter so the slow depends on dates that i filter and the amount of data

Comment: yeah , i  know that im mysql_query.. , this project its old 
my client suffer from slow query , now im making changes i made indexes to tables and i would like to display the percentage to tells the client thats it still looking not stuck , i tried to use bootstrap progress bar but the same thing wont get changes,

Answer (score 0):

Logically it will go like this:

```
$('#percents').val('<?php echo $percent; ?>');
```

but the information you provided in question is very less to be sure.

Comment: i already tried the same , with jquery and js 
but only alert or console.log works inside the script tag

Comment: are you 100% sure your php code is working completely fine? try adding an echo "end" like statement in bottom of php file if you are unsure coz i tried creating same code in localhost and its working fine for me.

Comment: YES iam sure 100 % , can you send me the code you created and let me check ?